# Under what condition is P/poly equal to the class of languages having Turing machines running in polynomial length with polynomial advice?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

Sanjeev Arora and Boaz Barak show the following :

> $P/poly = \cup_{c,d} DTIME (n^c)/n^d$

where $DTIME(n^c)/n^d$ is a Turing machine which is given an advice of length $O(n^d)$  and runs in $O(n^c)$ time. I do follow the proof. But I feel the  proof only holds if we assume that  $\forall n$ the advice given to any two $n$ length strings $x$ and $y$ is same.

But I am unable to see if the theorem still holds if the above condition if not applicable ?

Comment: The advice always depends only on the input length.

Comment: The standard advice model explicitly assumes that the advice is the same for all inputs of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P/Poly$ talks about circuit families for languages (different circuit $C_n$ for length $n$ inputs), it is natural to talk about an advice which is a function of the input's length alone.
Different advice for each string will make the class too big. For any $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$, your advice for some $x\in\Sigma ^*$ can be 1 if $x\in L$ and 0 otherwise.